# QSqlQuery Selects Deleted Table

Tags: sql-server, qsqlquery

I have a QT application and I am showing the user some data from ms sql database which is related to selected ID from comboBox object. My problem is, I've deleted all my tables on my ms sql server but my qt application still finds tables. Here is my sample code :

```
QString query = 'SELECT Date FROM [dbo].[Parametre] WHERE id=';
QString selected_item = this->ui->comboBox->currentText();
query.append(selected_item);
QSqlQuery qry;

if(qry.exec(query))
{
this->listWidget->addItem->qry.value(0).toString();
}
else
{
qDebug()<<qry.lastError();
}
```

There's no valid table in my ms sql database but it still writes deleted Date's on my listWidget object. My question is what causes this problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: I have removed [tag:mysql] as it doesn't use a `dbo` schema. Please only tag the RDBMS you are actually using. Thanks.

Comment: First thing to do in such situations is to locate the ACTUAL connection string used to make your connections. Do not assume anything - debug your code and evaluate that  string when you stop in the debugger immediately on the line that makes the connection. Does your connection logic use a substitution string?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't close my database connection on my previous version on my application. I changed this and now I am closing my connection via exit button and my problem solved. For those have same problem try to close your database connection and open new connection everytime you run your application. If you did not do this qt forces sql to close connection and this causes some problems.